# pandas difference between resampling with 'Q' and 'QS'

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand the difference between `df.resample('Q')` and `df.resample('QS')`. It seems to produce the same groups in any scenario, the only difference being the index labels.

Is the index labeling truly the only difference? If not, can somebody please show me a minimal example where `'Q'` and `'QS'` produce different groupings?

Related documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html), [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin), but it's opaque to me.

Comment: Your intuition is right, there is no difference between the two other than index. `Q` stands for quarter end, `QS` stands for quarter start.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thanks - can you explain why the groupings become different when I specify a month, e.g. `'Q-DEC'` versus `'QS-DEC'`? This all seems very inconsistent to me.